# Asp.net Login Control Error : Database '' does not exist. Make sure that the name is entered correctly

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

Using the Login Control from the toolbar: I am unsure as to why I am getting this error when I try to log in.  The database does exist:

```
{"Database 'Data Source=(LocalDB)\\v11' does not exist. Make sure that the name is entered correctly."}
```

Login.aspx.cs

```
 protected void ValidateUser(object sender, AuthenticateEventArgs e)
    {
        int userId = 0;
        string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["LoginConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(constr))
            {
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", Login1.UserName);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", Login1.Password);
                cmd.Connection = con;
                con.Open();
                userId = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
                con.Close();
            }
            switch (userId)
            {
                case -1:
                    Login1.FailureText = "Username and/or password is incorrect.";
                    break;
                case -2:
                    Login1.FailureText = "Account has not been activated.";
                    break;
                default:
                    FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(Login1.UserName, Login1.RememberMeSet);
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
```

I have a user table with two columns username and password.  I am using visual Studio 2014 to code with c# and ASP.net Web forms and SQL Sever Express 2012.

**Stack Trace**

```
 [SqlException (0x80131904): Database 'Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11' does not exist. Make sure that the name is entered correctly.]
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction) +1789294
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction) +5340642
   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose) +244
   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady) +1691
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryConsumeMetaData() +61
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData() +90
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString) +377
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, SqlDataReader ds) +1421
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite) +177
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method) +53
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteScalar() +152
   Login.ValidateUser(Object sender, AuthenticateEventArgs e) in c:\Users\Michelle\Desktop\COMF510_65300_HS_task_2\Login.aspx.cs:34
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Login.OnAuthenticate(AuthenticateEventArgs e) +9614658
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Login.AttemptLogin() +119
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Login.OnBubbleEvent(Object source, EventArgs e) +75
   System.Web.UI.Control.RaiseBubbleEvent(Object source, EventArgs args) +37
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnCommand(CommandEventArgs e) +114
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +159
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +10
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument) +13
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData) +35
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +1724
```

**Source error: Line 34**

```
Line 32:                 cmd.Connection = con;
Line 33:                 con.Open();
Line 34:                 userId = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
Line 35:                 con.Close();
Line 36:             }
```

Comment: Where is the "LoginConnectionString" stored? Could you show that code/confif file? The error indicates that there is no database in this connectionstring, which could mean an empty connectionstring

Comment: thank you I will check now :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your connection string doesn't look right. You should be following this format for localdb:

```
<add name="ConnectionStringName"
    providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
    connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFileName=|DataDirectory|\DatabaseFileName.mdf;InitialCatalog=DatabaseName;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True" />
```

|DataDirectory| is a substitution string. You can configure the location of your database file separately.

As an option, you can set it:

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetData("DataDirectory", "C:\myDB");
```

Comment: This is my connection string in config:  <add name="LoginConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\WebApps.mdf;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>

Comment: If you are using the DataDirectory feature, the localdb should be in the App_Data folder. If not, you need to set it.

Comment: Yep the mdf file is my App_Data folder called WebApps.mdf but when I opened Server Explorer is called LoginConnectionString ????

Comment: LoginConnectionString is the name you gave the connection string. What are you looking at in Server Explorer? Not following.

Comment: my database has renamed its self to the name of my connectionstring. Probably should just redo?

Comment: I thought it might have gotten renamed, but wasn't sure - odd. Yeah, just redo and you should be all set.

Comment: There is no issue with database or connectionstring so it must be the code?

Comment: I have created a new mdf file, added tables etc set up connectstring and even set up a gridview to test connection and display table... still the exact same error!

Comment: What stored procedure are you executing? I don't see it in your code. All I see is you setting up the command. Though, I think that is a different issue.

Also, since this isn't working - try setting the DataDirectory as I showed in my answer. There are plenty of examples online as well.